# CircleCi terraform path doesn't exist

Tags: terraform, circleci

Im using official terraform orb for CircleCi pipelines. I would like to specify path to my terraform code, but the error shows that path doesn't exist. But when I'm going into docker which run that job, that path is available. I don't understand why.

```
jobs:
  - terraform/fmt:
      checkout: true
      path: 'project/terraform/'
      context: terraform
```

Comment: It could also be a permissions error. Could you update the question with the error thrown by the Circle job?

Comment: Path does not exist: "project/terraform"

Exited with code exit status 1

CircleCI received exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

We are on the same page. I have seen this error happening with me before and then without any changes on my side the pipeline started to work again. I think there is a problem on CircleCI

Comment: It's a problem with terraform fmt I think. I changed it into my own terraform script and it's working ok